# Lenovo T480 + Dock + 2 Dell P2415Q + Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have Lenoto T480 notebook with Ubuntu 18.04.1 connected with dock station. I want to connect 2 dell P2415Q displays - first via display port on dock station, second via HDMI port directly to notebook. When i'm trying to connect only 1 display via DP or HDMI it's working fine. When I conntect second display it doesn't work.
I have intel core i7-8550U processor with intel HD 620 graphics.

I would be very thankful for help with my problem.

Comment: I have similar issues (s https://redd.it/9wfaew/), for me it helped always to power up the laptop and login first and then connect it to the screens. But at the moment (I think with GNOME Shell 3.28.3) it getting worse...

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt work for me... I tried to turn off laptop and power on when it was connected/disconnected to dock station, but nothing helps me.

Comment: Try ubuntu 18.10 with a live USB stick... In that reddit thread somebody posted that this problems where gone with 18.10

Comment: Pls give feedback if that worked out for you...

Comment: It seems that problem not in OS. I successfully connected FHD display via docks VGA port. But still can't do it via HDMI port directly. Now I'm using three displays: built in, 4K and FHD connected through dock station